# VWD 2010 express in Windows 7 design mode problems

Tags: vwdexpress

So far I was using `VWD 2010` express quite smoothly on Windows XP. Now I have got a new laptop - with Windows 7 64 bit. Yesterday I installed `VWD 2010 express`. I transfered all my data to the new laptop. When I open an existing project, it opened well and even runs very well. But when I am design mode I have lots of problems like

1. Cursor is not seen in the .aspx page and scrolling does not work. Cant edit anything. However .aspx.cs works normally
2. when I press `Ctrl + F`, Find window opens up but when I give find next, the instance is not seen and the page does not navigate to the instance
3. When I double click on a file in the solution explorer, i dont see it open. But when I minimise the entire VWD and maximise it, I see that the clicked page is open.
4. sometimes (mostly just after the project is loaded) part of the screen is black and when i minimise VWD and maximise, the page is properly shown.

I tried Repair and also uninstalled and reinstalled the entire VWD 2010 express - the problem still exists. I dont know what problem it could be. I did not encounter any problem while installing VWD. Could this be a VWD problem or memory problem (8GB RAM) or graphic card(dedicated) problem? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue yesterday, I logged in to the forum today to post my solution so that it helps someone later. Here is what I did:

I opened the "Compatibility Troubleshooter" in the control panel and identitified that there is a compatibility issue. So I made changes to open VWDexpress in the compatible mode (In my case it was Windows XP service pack2) and saved the settings. Now it works very well.